# RazorSQL profiles, command line calls & windows task user mixup

Tags: windows, odbc, scheduled-tasks, clarion, razorsql

They might be quite obscure: i enjoy RazorSQL for all it can do, and it is the only tool i found that talks properly is Clarions's ODBC driver. It also allows for awesome command line calls to export data.

Trouble is: RazorSQL stores profile connection information based on the user that installed it, and when you set a Windows task to run the batch files of all the groovy export commands, the internal batch file fail without external notification because the user is SYSTEM (as we don't want this tied to any one user)..

I do not recall if there was an option on install allowing profiles to be seen by all, as i normally set this to everyone on my dev box (as it is only me).

So the question: has anyone encountered this obscure scenario, and knows how to have RazorSQL look in a generic location for connection details?

Comment: I thought this would be rather obscure, but perhaps somebody from RazorSQL will take note and attempt an answer..

Comment: Some of my experience with TPS ODBC driver with Excel and C#, it´s just work with 32 bits (test it with RazorSQL 32 bits and ODBC 32 bits configuration)

Comment: thx YM, but that was not the question. It is working fine, just not in the scenario outlined.

Answer (score 0):

RazorSQL checks for system property named "razorPortable". When defined with a value of "portable" it keeps all its stuff in a RazorSQL folder under its main directory, so shared by all users launching it with said property defined.

So you know the drill: edit some of the bundled bat files and add `-DrazorPortable=portable` to the command line.

You'll need to re-enter yout registration code, connection profiles, preferences, etc. Or you can manually move them.